# Attach disk drive in Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mac, hfs+, hdiutil

Is there a Linux equivalent of the Mac's

```
sudo hdiutil attach -imagekey -diskimage-class=CRawDiskImage  -nomount
```

I have an imagine I want to attach as a disk drive, but I don't want to mount it. The image is HFS+ formatted and I'm running Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux has [losetup](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/losetup8.html) which you can use to attach a file to the system as a block device.  E.g.

```
losetup /dev/loop0 macfoo.dmg
```